# Wordpress hiding wp-admin for protection with htacess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to change the url name from `site/wp-admin` to `site/dashboard`

I have added this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ dashboard/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard(.*)$ wp-admin$1
```

This only makes me available to use site/dashboard but site/wp-admin is still available. Is there a way to hide this so i can only access site/dashboard?

I don't want to use a `plugin` for this. It has to be manually.

Thanks in advance
- Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the best solution would be to move the wordpress core to a different directory and keep only wp-content in the root. Your rewrites could create some problems because wordpress itself would not know about the redirection and could not handle it (pointing to the /wp-admin/ directory).

You can install wordpress in a separate subfolder following this instructions:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Moving_a_Root_install_to_its_own_directory and keep the wp-content folder in the root with one config line: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder